# How to get rid of all these CiviCRM questions?

Tags: discussion

Yes, CiviCRM is technically a Drupal module, but it's also a standalone application with its own community of users (who have some overlap with the Drupal community, but also WP and Joomla folks).

So it seems to make sense to start a [separate SE site for CiviCRM](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm?referrer=8gfMpihOSETXeNHrjdyxXQ2). You can help get it off the ground by clicking to support this initiative!

As a member of both communities, I want to say you're all the best! Thanks for all the mutual support over the years.

Answer (score 11):

We don't want to get rid of any of the CiviCRM questions.  If and when the Area 51 proposal gets approved, and passes beta, we can consider selective migration of questions to there.  Until then, I don't have problems with these unless they are so specific to CiviCRM to not be beneficial outside the CiviCRM community.

Comment: Also note that migration of content older than 60 days is not possible. There are a dozen and more questions on Stack Overflow that I'd really like to have over here, but them's the rules. Old content that we want to keep open is here to stay

Comment: The SE team can migrate things over 60 days old; they did that as part of the MSO / MSE divorce.  But, that doesn't mean that they would do it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

## All

Do not.

## Many

Vote to close as bugreports, if you see questions about SQL syntax errors, missing elements etc. Vote to close as off-topic, if it is about CiviCRM application, not Drupal module. If you can't vote, flag.

---

And don't forget you can put [civicrm](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civicrm) on your list of ignored tags.

Comment: As we try to get questions and answers about CiviCRM in the set of StackExchange community so our community members can build reputation in order to launch the beta, we were thinking of putting the questions into the WordPress and Drupal communities. Should we use StackOverflow.com instead if the questions are purely CiviCRM and not, eg, Drupal related?

Comment: @Joe if the questions don't relate to Drupal, please don't ask them here (they will just be closed anyway). If they relate to programming, Stack Overflow is definitely an option

Comment: Agreed. But CiviCRM integrates fairly deeply into views, webform (via webform_civicrm), and actions and triggers, etc. And sometimes people running Drupal/CiviCRM aren't sure where a problem is, or whether solutions will be exclusive to CiviCRM or will involve one or more modules or hooks from Drupal.

Comment: @Joe Where there's a hope of a Drupal-based solution, a question is fine, encouraged even. It's just the ones that would definitely be platform-agnostic that we need to avoid. Admittedly that can't always be identified until the community has had a chance t review the question, so I guess I'm just saying if anything is _blatantly_ a civi-only question it shouldn't be asked. And if turns out not to be answerable from a Drupal point of view, it'll almost definitely be closed as off topic. Those types are likely to be the minority I think

Comment: Makes sense, Clive. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

For projects like CiviCRM trying to establish a site on StackExchange, this is a chicken and egg problem. We do acknowledge and appreciate all the help that the Drupal project and community has given to CiviCRM over the past decade.

So once again, while we **[get our own site bootstrapped on Stack Exchange via area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm)**, please do help us out and vote for us. Once we have our own little SE play-pen, we promise to keep most civi related discussion there.

Comment: As long as your questions are not merely bugreports (I've seem at least one about MySQL syntax error...), hosting requests, etc, and are abut Drupal side of this issue, you are and will be welcomed here. Sadly, when [highly upvoted answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/16515/16495) happens to be, basically, link only ones (two other like that deleted today), you yourselves make CiviCRM look bad. Not because it's bad, because it attracts low quality content.

Answer (score 1):

We don't get ride of questions, if those are perfectly on-topic and good quality for *Drupal Answers*. We cannot even migrate questions that are too old (i.e. asked more than 60 days ago).

When the proposal makes into a Stack Exchange site, we will migrate those questions that are pretty much more about CiviCRM than Drupal. It will be the users who will start using the site which gives them more helpful answers than the other. That is what happened when *Drupal Answers* was created: Users moved from asking Drupal questions on *Stack Overflow* to asking there on *Drupal Answers*. There are still Drupal questions asked on *Stack Overflow*, but that it is not something that we can stop, especially for those users who ask more questions about other programming topics than Drupal.